# In Spring Data Rest, How to prevent DELETE HTTP methods from being exported from my JpaRepository?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring-data-rest and I have a JpaRepository like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "projects")
public interface ProjectsRepository extends JpaRepository<MetricsProjects, Integer> {...}
```

My repository interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "projects")
public interface ProjectsRepository extends JpaRepository<MetricsProjects, Integer> {
    
    List<MetricsProjects> findByProjectName(String projectName);
    
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void deleteById(Integer id);
    
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void delete(MetricsProjects entity);
    
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends MetricsProjects> entities);
    
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void deleteAll();
    
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void deleteInBatch(Iterable<MetricsProjects> entities);
    
    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    public void deleteAllInBatch();

}
```

I've also added disableDefaultExposure() , as suggested somewhere.

My Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringDataRestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration restConfig) {
        restConfig.disableDefaultExposure();
    }

}
```

But I still see the DELETE methods exposed from my Swagger-UI, how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller method for the DELETE endpoint and return 405 Method Not Allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` to

```
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration restConfig) {
        restConfig.getExposureConfiguration()
                .forDomainType(put the class type here)
                .withItemExposure((metdata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.DELETE))
                .withCollectionExposure((metdata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.DELETE));
    }
```

Replace put the class type here with the className.class, for example if the className is **MetricsProjects**, put **MetricsProjects.class** there.

[Here is additional info.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-customize-http-endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

To disable the display of a specific endpoint in Swagger (Springfox library), I have added the annotation ***ApiIgnore*** on the associated method in repository class :

```
 @Override
 @ApiIgnore
 @RestResource(exported = false)
 public void deleteById(Integer id);
```